# Why is `std::remove_const` not removing the `const`-ness of a reference object when used with `decltype`?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, decltype, reference-type

```
#define T int
int main ()
{
  const T x = 2;
  // (1) -- type of `x` is compared with `T`
  static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_const<decltype(x)>::type, T>::value, "Not same");
  // (2) -- type of `x` is compared with `const T`
  static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_const<decltype(x)>::type, const T>::value, "Not same");
}
```

Above code works as expected. Where (1) passes and (2) fails.

However, it happens other way around, viz. (1) fails and (2) passes, if I make following change:

```
#define T int& // <--- added reference
```

Why does it happen so?

With the similar code of `decltype`, what can we add to the code, so that (1) passes with reference & non-reference types both, i.e. `int&` & `int`?
Possible solution with `const_cast` are also welcome.

---

**Note**: Since I want to macro-fy the removal of `const` from an object; I have used `decltype`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've used a textual substitution macro instead of a typedef, you got `const int& x`.

`const int&` is not a `const` type, so `remove_const` does nothing.

It's impossible to change `const`-ness of a reference, because C++ does not have any reference-mutating operations.

If you want to remove the innermost `const` (where `const T` would have placed it), then this works:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_deepest_const_impl { typedef T type; };

template <typename T>
struct remove_deepest_const_impl<const T> { typedef T type; };

template <typename T>
struct remove_deepest_const_impl<T*>
{ typedef typename remove_deepest_const_impl<T>::type* type; };

template <typename T>
struct remove_deepest_const_impl<T* const>
{ typedef typename remove_deepest_const_impl<T>::type* const type; };

template <typename T>
struct remove_deepest_const_impl<T&>
{ typedef typename remove_deepest_const_impl<T>::type& type; };

template <typename T>
struct remove_deepest_const_impl<T&&>
{ typedef typename remove_deepest_const_impl<T>::type&& type; };

template <typename T> using remove_deepest_const
       = typename remove_deepest_const_impl<T>::type;
```

Demonstration: https://rextester.com/OUTIN28468

Comment: I tried `remove_reference`, and that also didn't work. May be I didn't try all the possible options. Is that of any help in this scenario?